# Suppress file output in a python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io

I have a binary executable that when run writes ~10 or so files and also writes to stdout.
For some reason the program does not provide the option to not write any of these files.

I'd like to run this program as a python subprocess, but to reduce I/O operations I would like to prevent the files from being written to disk altogether and collect only the stdout. Is this possible?

I've tried running subprocess.run with capture_output=True and a few other flags but haven't had any luck.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Unless it takes the filenames as arguments, there's nothing you can do to stop it from writing to the files. It's not using stdout, so `capture_output` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If it does take them as arguments, use `/dev/null` as the filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough memory you can use [`/dev/shm`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html).

```bash
$ df -h
tmpfs               16G    4,0K   16G   1% /dev/shm
```

Assuming your binary write files to current working directory:

```py
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir="/dev/shm") as workdir:
    p = subprocess.run(("binary",), capture_output=True, cwd=workdir)
```

If memory is a problem, you can override [`open`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open) function using [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://catonmat.net/simple-ld-preload-tutorial-part-two) and redirect writes to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Using /dev/shm in combination with the subprocess worked perfectly for me. Thanks very much!